# WPF: Focus navigation over different instances of a user control

Tags: c#, wpf, focus

I have a user control (ip address) in which there are four textbox. 
What I expect is that if the user press the tab button in one textbox the focus switch to the next one (without going outside the ip address control). Everything works fine if I have one control.

If I have more ip address control in one container and I press tab in one text box of one control then the focus switch to the same text box of the other control.

Take a look at the image below: if I press "tab" when the focus is in 1 then it goes to 2.

[image: focus error]

How can I change my user control so that the focus doesn't "jump" outside the user control?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want tab navigation to be contained within your control set  **[KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigation.tabnavigation(v=vs.110).aspx)** attached property to **`Contained`** on UserControl.

```
<UserControl KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Contained">
  .....
</UserControl>
```

Or in case you want it to be cycle within UserControl i.e. from last to first and back to last textBox set it to **`Cycle`**.

```
<UserControl KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle">
  .....
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rohit it works. Anyway I have another little problem: when the focus reach the last textbox in the user control the user would expect that the focus goes on the first text box of the next user control. What happens is that the focus goes in the ribbon of the application. Is there any way to get the expected behavior?

Comment: Try setting `KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue"` and also you can set `TabIndex` on elements to specify the order in which you want Tab to move from one control to other. It moves from lower tab index to next higher tab index.

Comment: Thanks again Rohit. I finally resolved by settings Local on the KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation attacched property.